# AngularJS Bindings & JQuery .text()

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am creating a small attribute directive to disable and change the text of a button that is processing. Here is the code:

```
.directive('ajaxDisabled', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var originalText = $(element).text();
            scope.$parent.$watch('processing', function(val) {
                if (val) {
                    $(element).attr('disabled', true);
                    $(element).text('Loading...');
                } else {
                    $(element).attr('disabled', false);
                    $(element).text(originalText);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

My problem is that $(element).text(); gets the element's text before AngularJS has applied it, so it shows {{submitLabel}} rather than its value. How can I get the bound value and not the expression?

Comment: why are you using jQuery for any of this? Can all be done using angular built in directives and markup expressions

Comment: Can you give me some reference material?

Comment: sure...look at `ng-disabled` in docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link function returned from directive factory function will be called before your scope is evaluated. In your code, you store `originalText` at the time link function is executed so that why you get `{{submitLabel}}` which is un-evaluated text inside the element.

You need to get original text at the time `processing` is changed, that is inside function you pass into `$watch`

```
scope.$parent.$watch('processing', function(val) {
    // -- set your original text here --
    var originalText = ...
    if (val) {
        element.attr('disabled', true);
        element.text('Loading...');
    } else {
        element.attr('disabled', false);
        element.text(originalText);
    }
});
```

And you don't need `$()` because angular already wrapped your element with jQuery lite. See [this document](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using jQuery explicitly here.  Rather, use the jQuery built into Angular to manipulate and evaluate the element.  It will keep everything within the correct digest cycle.  I would recommend looking at ng-disabled though and other built-in directives that may help.

```
.directive('ajaxDisabled', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            //element is an angular element which has builtin function (and is actually a jQuery object)
            var originalText = element.text();
            scope.$parent.$watch('processing', function(val) {
                if (val) {
                    element.attr('disabled', true);
                    element.text('Loading...');
                } else {
                    element.attr('disabled', false);
                    element.text(originalText);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a more generic approach. You see, your directive is strongly coupled with the parent scope: `scope.$parent.$watch('processing',...)`. Below is a more generic directive that can be used as:

```
<button ng-click="..." ajax-disabled="busy">Dummy</button>
```

Where `busy` can be any boolean expression. In the example below, the button will be enabled/disabled according to the value of the boolean; the action can be customized according to your needs however:

```
app.directive("ajaxDisabled", function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
            var getter = $parse(attrs.ajaxDisabled);
            scope.$watch(getter, function(newval, oldval) {
                if( newval === true ) {
                    element.attr("disabled", true);
                }
                else {
                    element.attr("disabled", false);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/5LChR/